# JSONPath and regex: filter to search end substring

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

I need to extract "https://www.domain3.com" from this JSON

```
{
    "jobs": [
        {
            "name": "alfa",
            "url": "https://www.domain1.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "beta_publish",
            "url": "https://www.domain2.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "gammma_release",
            "url": "https://www.domain3.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

using a regular expression.

I'm trying to use this one (in https://www.jsonquerytool.com/ ...),

```
$..jobs[?(@.name=~/release*?/i)].url
```

but it doesn't work, but if I try to use it in https://regex101.com/ it seems to work fine.

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `match` instead of `=~`

JSONPath

```
$.jobs[?(@.name.match(/release/i))].url
```

[image]